# How to create and add a loop in existing table

Tags: php

for example i already have an existing table name (Bronze)
what i want is to create  an another table called Bronze1,Bronze2,Bronze3,Bronze4, and so on . . in the table name

this is the sample of my code please help

```
for($i = 1; $i<99 ; $i++) {

   $this_table = 'Bronze'.$i;

   $create =mysql_query("Create Table $this_table")
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: i don't know how to put the right code in the loop there to create the table bronze1,bronze2,bronze3, and so on. so hard to explain >.< can give me an example that might work sir?

Comment: how can you create a table without column list?

Comment: You want to make 2 tabels in 1 loop?, Just store the tables in a variable and ouput them after the loop.

Comment: i want to create it 1by1 for example bronze1 already created ,then the nxt time i refresh the php  bronze2 will be created then bronze3,then bronze4 . ..

Answer (score 1):

Try this SQL-statement:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl;
```

in your case:

```
for($i = 1; $i<99 ; $i++) {
   $this_table = 'Bronze'.$i;
   $create =mysql_query("Create Table $this_table LIKE Bronze")
}
```

that will create a table based on another one.